# Alternatives to switching power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, noise

I designed an analog board using a ±12V switching power supply as the input source.
Now I am wondering to desgin the 2nd version of it and enhance some aspects including eliminating a few tens mV noise
that I know that a part of it is due to switching power supply.
There are two solutions I think of them:

1. Using transformer, rectifier, caps, and then linear regulator to produce ±12V.
2. Using a switching power supply with ±15V output (or higher) and then linear regulators with ±12V output.

The first solution is common and straightforward. But does solution 2 make noise less than previous board?
if yes which solution will make less noise, solution 1 or 2?

If my question was not clear, please `Assume that I definitely know that the noise comes from the switching regulator`.

Comment: Any answer has to assume that you definitely know that the noise comes from the switching regulator and not some ground loop. Have you tried running from a stable 12-0-12 DC supply? Solution 2 does work BTW but who can say in your situation?

Comment: The switching regulator will generate high frequency noise, which will be largely, but perhaps not entirely attenuated by the linear regulator. The linear supply will generate lower frequency noise, which will be largely, but perhaps not entirely attenuated by the linear regulator. Does the spectrum of the noise matter to you?

Comment: @Andyaka What do you mean by `a stable 12-0-12 DC supply`? I tried with two 12V batteries and noise was somewhat suppressed.

Comment: How much is the noise now? How does that compare to similar designs? Maybe it just is what you can expect from such a design? How low do you need the noise to be, what is your **target**? Explain how much noise can be tolerated. Realize that "no noise" means using a **battery** and even a battery still has some noise. What if your "improved design" still has too much noise? **Don't fall into the trap of improving something without knowing what your goal is.**

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Now my goal is only to know what the order of three solutions is based on the noise they generate. **Solution 0:** a lonely switching power supply, **Solution 1:** a linear power supply, and **Solution 2:** linear regulators in series with a switching power supply.

Comment: Any of them can be made to meet any desired standard. Consider starting with a suitable L-C filter on the existing supply and make sure your grounding arrangements are clean.

Comment: Many professional linear lab PSU use a 1st stage switcher with SCRs, phase angle control, not high freq. SMPS. Then a large LC filter and capacitor bank, then a very fast linear stage, almost no capacitance on output. IMO, the SMPS + linear is not a good solution, since the linear part wouldn't eliminate the HF noise.

Comment: *what the order of three solutions is based on the noise they generate.* Impossible to answer as **it depends** on many things. But you still appear to be searching for "the best" without discussing what you actually need. A battery has the lowest noise so why not use that? *Because batteries drain.* True, so use a linear supply. *It dissipates too much power.* Then use a switching supply. *It generates too much noise.* **Specify** how much noise you can tolerate, **zero** is not an answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, the noise was around 160mV. With batteries it went to less than 50mV being desired for me.

Comment: If you already have 50 mV with batteries then you need to add **power supply decoupling** in the rest of the circuit. You mention some numbers but you fail to say if these numbers are OK or not. 50 mV or 160 mV can be a lot for a sensitive analog circuit. It can be totally fine for a digital only circuit.

Comment: Without a schematic an exact solution would be a lucky guess. Since you designed the analog board and you still have noise with batteries I am assuming part of your problem is in your analog design. One trick in analog design is to use differential amplifiers and keep the noise in common mode. I am assuming the board was properly decoupled with capacitors etc.